# Javascript Remove HTML Tags List to <br/>

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace html tags list in javascript

```
var value1 = " <ul>
             <li>Text1</li>
             <li>Text1</li>
             </ul> "
```

into

```
value1 = " <br/> text1 <br/> text2 "
```

with REGEX REPLACE thing ?

UPDATE :

i try this works, but too long script.

```
value1 = value1.replace(/<li>/g, "<p>");
value1 = value1.replace(/<\/li>/g, "</p>");
value1 = value1.replace(/<\/ul>/g, "</p>");
value1= value1.replace(/<ul>/g, "<p>");
value1 = value1.replace(/<\/ol>/g, "</p>");
value1 = value1.replace(/<ol>/g, "<p>");
```

Comment: If you want to use a regex, and if your string is consistent enough, this can be done, but you should try it for yourself instead of just asking others how to do it.

Comment: Do you have to do it with regex? Why not manipulate the DOM directly?

Comment: @Barmar var 'value1' is result from manipulate the DOM after i request ajax data. Then insert value1 into listview jquery mobile, but jqm read it as new listview. Can you help me?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can do `dom1=$(value1)` to parse it into disconnected DOM elements, and then use jQuery's DOM manipulation methods.

Comment: -1: I have downvoted this question, but don't take it personally.  I downvoted because to the best of my knowledge, Regex is a very poor choice of tools to search for HTML tags. jQuery, as suggested by @Barmar, is a much better choice, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below... may be it will help you...

Fiddle 1 : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/105/

Fiddle 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/107/

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
var result = value1.replace(/<li>/ig," ").replace(regex, "").replace(/ +/g,"<br/>");
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the job that you are asking:

> ```
> value1.replace(/<li>/ig, '<br>').replace(/<\/li>/ig, '').replace(/<\/?ul>/ig, '')
> ```

But I suggest get the element in an array and return it properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $els = $(value1);
$("<li>", $els).unWrap().replaceWith(function() { return "<br/>"+$(this).text(); });
```

Comment: Asker is not necessarily using jQuery.

Comment: @Marc He said he's using jQuery mobile in a comment.